# YouTube Channels: list API not returning in order

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having an issue, where even though I enter the channel IDs in order, there are times when it doesn't return them (items) in the same order.

Why is that? Most of the time it returns it in order, but often not.

I'm using the YouTube API v3 Channels:list

```
id: UCdSr4xliU8yDyS1aGnCUMTA,UCVrZceJ6Ux-Us3sKCw_6sIg,UCv9Edl_WbtbPeURPtFDo-uA,UCovb8rgpCANx6nwDwnW0Uqg,UCPkOhci8gkwL7p6hxIJ2WQw
```

part: snippet,contentDetails,statistics

It even does this glitch in the YouTube API tester and it's hard to combine live Streaming data with this API, as this one keeps failing at keeping it in order.

Comment: Which is the expected order?, please [edit] your question.